# Displaying conditional jsx based on the state of info in a json file

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a problem where I am trying to check data that's been fetched from an API. If a certain object in my JSON file has information, I want "off-track" to show in my jsx. I have used a ternary operator to check if the length of the elements under this json object is greater than 0, and if so the words "off-track" should show. My code is below

```
const Card = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const getData = () => {
    fetch('data.json', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.personal.publicInfo.courtAndInsolvencies)
        setData(data)
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
}, [])

const personalInfo = data.personal.publicInfo.courtAndInsolvencies.length;
```

return (

```
<>
    <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header'>
            <p className='tracker'>off track</p>
            <p className='impact impact-header'></p>
        </div>
        <h2 className='card-heading'>Public information</h2>
        <p className='card-paragraph'>Bankruptcies and individual voluntary arrangements can damage your score</p>
        {personalInfo > 0 &&
        <p className='impact impact-footer'>off track</p> }
    </div>
```

Kindly assist:)

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that `data.personal.publicInfo.courtAndInsolvencies` is an object and you want to check if it is empty or not:

```
let myObj=data.personal.publicInfo.courtAndInsolvencies
let isEmpty=Object.keys(myObj).length === 0
```

`isEmpty` will return true if `myObj` is empty

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quite come right but I did something else alternatively. Thanks